# How to convert a function to the form y = A sin(Bx + C) + D to find the phase shift, period, and frequencies?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

The question asks us to find the period of the function $y=\sin(√2x) + \sin(3√2x)$. I usually know how to find the period and all that in the format of $y = A \sin(Bx + C) + D$, but how do I get this function to get in that format?

Comment: Find the period of each. You will find that one period is a multiple of the other, so the period of the sum of the two periodic functions will be the period of the one with the larger period.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 3 questions in the last few hours. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: Notice that the problem does not require you to put the function into the form $y = A \sin(Bx + C) + D$ and as @Martin points out, it cannot be put into that form. If two periodic functions have periods which are integer multiples of a common unit, say $3u$ and $5u$, then the period of a linear combination of the two will be the least common multiple of the two, $15u$.

Answer (score 3):

After the substitution $t=\sqrt2x$, you are essentially asking whether you can express
$$f(t)=\sin t+\sin3t$$
in the desired form.

Using some trigonometric identities it is not difficult to find out that
$$\sin t+\sin 3t = 2\sin t\cos 2t.\tag{1}$$
(Probably the quickest way to see this is to use [product-to-sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) $\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=2\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2$.)

It is clear that the function $f(t)$ is odd. So if it has form $A\sin(Bt+C)+D$, then $D=0$ and $C=0$

From $(1) $you can see that this function has zeroes for $t=0$, $t=\pi/2$ and $t=\pi$, but we also have $f(t)\ge0$ for any $t\in[0,\pi]$. This means that the function does not have the form $A\sin Bt$.

You can even try to draw a plot. Here is what [WolframAlpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(t)%2Bsin(3t)).

[image: Graph of sin(t)+sin(3t)]

If you want to sketch such graph by hand, probably the best way is to plot $\sin t$ and $\sin 3t$ first and then simply add (superpose) them together. You can again [try Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin(t)%2Bsin(3t),+sin(t),+sin(3t)).

[image: graph of sin(t), sin(3t) and their sum]